# Equals method in a generic n-ary tree

Tags: java, arrays, tree, equals

I have this n-ary tree implementation, where each tree class stores the data and it's children in an array.

Also there is my **incomplete** method `equals()`.

```
public class ArrayNTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements NTree<T>, Cloneable {

/* Data of the tree*/
private T data;

/* Primary array to store the children */
private ArrayNTree<T>[] children;

...

public boolean equals(Object other) { // FIXME

    if (this == other)
        return true;

    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if(other instanceof ArrayNTree)
        return sameTree( (ArrayNTree<T>) other );

    return false;
}

private boolean sameTree(ArrayNTree<T> xpto) {
    return (this.data == xpto.data &&
            //this.children == xpto.children && ???????
            this.size == xpto.size);
}
```

My main doubt is how do I go through every child and compare with the other tree since this is an array I think it makes the job a little harder

Comment: Have you tried `Arrays.deepEquals(Object[] a1, Object[] a2)` ?

Comment: I am aware of deepEquals, I was just wondering if there was a different way to pursue this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  if `data` or `size` is different return `false`

Then,  check its `children`

---

1. one by one:

   ```
   private boolean sameTree(ArrayNTree<T> xpto) {
       if(this.data != xpto.data || this.size != xpto.size)
           return false;
       for(int i = 0; i<this.children.length: i++){
           if(!this.children[i].equals(xpto.children[i]))
                return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Using `Arrays.deepEquals()`

   ```
   private boolean sameTree(ArrayNTree<T> xpto) {
       return this.data == xpto.data && 
              this.size != xpto.size && 
              Arrays.deepEquals(this.children, xpto.equals);
   }
   ```